# Materialize Pagination Link Style Error in Laravel 5.8

Tags: css, laravel, datatable, pagination, materialize

I created a datatable by using Laravel Pagination and Materialize CSS, but when I create the Pagination Link by using `{!! $users->render() !!}` the pagination links appear not properly like this:

[image]

And how to show it more stylish like the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/pagination.html#!) ?

Comment: Does the Pagination work properly?

Comment: Yes, the pagination works fine.

Comment: So maybe your problem is conflicting css rules. check the pagination css using inspect element in browser.

Answer (score 1):

By Default Laravel uses Bootstrap for its pagination, We need to customize it if we are using another framework. Since the stylesheets can conflict with each other.

I have followed the Laravel [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view) to get the work done.

**First**,

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This will publish the file's which we can edit,

Follow the path to open the file

```
resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-4.blade.php
```

Here is the updated file for materialize pagination,

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true">
            <a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
        </li>
        @else
        <li>
            <a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl()}}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
        @endif

        {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
        @foreach ($elements as $element)
        {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
        @if (is_string($element))
        <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true"><a>{{ $element }}</a></li>
        @endif

        {{-- Array Of Links --}}
        @if (is_array($element))
        @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
        <li class="active"><a href="">{{ $page }}</a></li>
        @else
        <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
        @endif
        @endforeach
        @endif
        @endforeach

        {{-- Next Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li>
            <a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class=" disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
            <a href="" aria-hidden="true"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a>
        </li>
        @endif
    </ul>
</nav>
@endif
```

**Note :** 
Laravel Version 6 and materialize - 1.0.0

Hope, this will help some one looking for this in future..